# Can't use pipenv in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, pipenv

I am trying to use `pipenv` for the first time in `pycharm` base on The article [Configure a Pipenv environment﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pipenv.html)
. However, I followed these steps.

```
$ python3.9 -m site --user-base
/Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9
```

```
$ export PATH="$PATH://Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/bin"
```

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, I got this error [image]

Should i undo `$ export PATH="$PATH://Users/apple/Library/Python/3.9/bin"`? any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What `Pipenv executable` have you specified?

Comment: I don't even know what is `Pipenv executable`

Comment: See screenshots in the help you've mentioned, `Pipenv executable` should point to pipenv that could be found by `which pipenv`

Comment: @user2235698 I got `/usr/local/bin/pipenv` thank you solved I copied the path in pasted it in the settings